# Null Pointer Exception EntityManager spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

i'm getting a null pointer exception when i'm trying to persist.
i'm going to list files that i think related with the error .
can someone help me ?

this is my class opmanagerImpl

```
package com.ensi.dao;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.ensi.entitis.opération;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
public class opmanagerImpl implements opmanager {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="ERP_PCD")
    private EntityManager em;
    public opmanagerImpl(){};
    public void creerOpération(opération op) {
        if(em==null)System.out.print("error ");
            em.persist(op);
        }
    }
```

this is my persistence.xml

```xml
<persistence-unit name="ERP_PCD" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"      value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/persistance" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="ensien" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

this is my applicationContext.xml

```xml
<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.postgresql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/persistance"></property>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"></property>
    <property name="password" value="ensien"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="datasource"></property>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ERP_PCD"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="em" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
</bean> 
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean name="dao" class="com.ensi.dao.opmanagerImpl"> </bean>
<bean name="metier"  class="org.ensi.metier.TestImpl">
    <property name="op" ref="dao"></property>
</bean>
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
```

the main:

```
package com.ensi.dao;
import org.ensi.entitis.opération;
import org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.privilegedactions.GetConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class Maintest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        opmanagerImpl xx = new opmanagerImpl();
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:META-                  INF/applicationContext1.xml");
        opération op=new opération(15, 'f', 120, "bonjour", null, 12, 15);
        xx.creerOpération(op);
        //System.out.println("hiiiiiiiiiiii");
    }
}
```

Results:

```
252 [main] INFO org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext -     Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1b61d282:    startup date [Sat May 03 02:43:19 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
493 [main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -   Pre-instantiating singletons in   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5ab6e2e3: defining   beans []; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException   
at com.ensi.dao.opmanagerImpl.creerOpération(opmanagerImpl.java:19) 
at com.ensi.dao.Maintest.main(Maintest.java:16) error `
```

Comment: Well, if you read the stack trace and look at the line numbers, you have a pretty decent chance of figuring this out yourself...

Comment: as a side node: Try to stick with the common Java conventions: Class names should always start with a capital letter (`opmanagerImpl`), and don't use any fancy characters for source code (`creerOpération`). It's probably best to use English wherever you can (`createOperation`), certainly it makes it easier for others if you post your code here...

Comment: @user3580294 this isn't the case. `NullPointerException` is due to `EntityManager em` not being created by the container, and it is not that easy to understand the causes.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Looks to me like `EntityManager` is never initialized in the first place... Unless the annotations are supposed to take care of that?

Comment: @user3580294 yes, the annotations should initialize it. That's what make this problem not that easy.

Comment: Ah I see, that's something new for me. My apologies to @user3598020 for being so condescending

Answer (score 0):

T̶r̶y̶ ̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶

```
̶@̶P̶e̶r̶s̶i̶s̶t̶e̶n̶c̶e̶C̶o̶n̶t̶e̶x̶t̶(̶u̶n̶i̶t̶N̶a̶m̶e̶=̶"̶E̶R̶P̶_̶P̶C̶D̶"̶)̶
̶p̶r̶i̶v̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶E̶n̶t̶i̶t̶y̶M̶a̶n̶a̶g̶e̶r̶ ̶e̶m̶;̶
```

T̶o̶

```
@̶A̶u̶t̶o̶w̶i̶r̶e̶d̶ ̶
p̶r̶i̶v̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶E̶n̶t̶i̶t̶y̶M̶a̶n̶a̶g̶e̶r̶ ̶e̶m̶;̶
```

---

The problem is that you're manually creating opmanagerImpl xx instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    opmanagerImpl xx = new opmanagerImpl();
    //rest of the code...
}
```

When using Spring, you **should not** create your beans manually, instead let Spring create them and obtain an instance of the bean through the application context. Change the code to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:META-INF/applicationContext1.xml");
    opmanagerImpl xx = ctx.getBean("dao", opmanagerImpl .class);
    opération op = new opération(15, 'f', 120, "bonjour", null, 12, 15);
    xx.creerOpération(op);
    //System.out.println("hiiiiiiiiiiii");
}
```

Comment: @Luigui Mendoza yes it's the same error warning NullpointerException

Comment: thank you @Luigui Mendoza i hope that you can help me .

Comment: it says :no bean named dao @Luigui Mendoza
how can i solve this problem please ?

Comment: @user3598020 Which is strange because your application config file has `<bean name="dao" class="com.ensi.dao.opmanagerImpl"> </bean>` there, so **it must** exists. Are you sure you're loading the right configuration file?

Comment: what i should do ? verify the value of class ? 
i have three packages in my project and the path of opmanagerImpl is corectly spelled . what's the problem so ?

Comment: @user3598020 try changing `<bean name="dao" ...>` by `<bean id="dao" ...>` (where `...` is the rest of the content of that portion of the xml).

Comment: same error . No bean named 'dao' is defined @Luigui Mendoza

Comment: @Luigui Mendoza by copying the file applicationContext.xml and modifying the path a new error message printed :


Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/support/SpringFactoriesLoader
 at